# Downloading a genome file, but Ubuntu says file does not exist

Tags: ubuntu, bioinformatics

beginner Ubuntu user here:

I have been doing assignments from biostar, a bioinformatics textbook (https://www.biostarhandbook.com/unixanalyis.html), and the section that I am currently on (in the link) asks that I copy the link for a file called SGD_features.tab, from the yeast genome database (http://sgd-archive.yeastgenome.org/curation/chromosomal_feature/). Then, I need to use the "curl" command + the link to download the file. When I do this, the output is a long list of genes and their descriptions, as it should be. The section then instructs me to view the contents of the file with the "cat" command. So I move to a directory that I created called yeast_genome, and then I type "cat SGD_features.tab", to which the output is "cat: SGD_features.tab: No such file or directory". I thought that I just downloaded the file, so why is it saying that it does not exist.

Here is a simplified version of my process in code form:

```
# curl http://sgd-archive.yeastgenome.org/curation/chromosomal_feature/SGD_features.tab
```

```
# pwd
/
(bioinfo)
```

```
# cd root/butt/yeast_genome
(bioinfo)
```

```
# cat SGD_features.tab
cat: SGD_features.tab: No such file or directory
(bioinfo)
```

Why does the SGD file not exist even though I just downloaded it? Biostar said little about this issue. In my example code here, I just ommited a few of the (bioinfo), because it was redundant.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Because you didn't download it to `root/butt/yeast_genome`. You downloaded it somewhere else instead. If `pwd` gave you `/`, then you weren't in `root/butt/yeast_genome` when you downloaded the file to the current directory.

Comment: Even when I run it in root/butt/yeast_genome, it just says:    " cat: SGD_features.tab: No such file or directory". I did run it in the yeast_genome directory, though I forgot to mention it in my explanation in the previous post.

Comment: There are only two possibilities here: 1) curl was unable to download the file, or 2) the file is not in the directory you think it's in. There isn't anything else possible. You need to find out which it is - we can't search your drive to see if the file is there or not. (As an aside, why are you running as `root` when you're downloading files from the internet? It's a major security risk.)